# Workbox is not treating iframe src requests as a valid route to intercept

Tags: javascript, workbox

I have a service worker on my page that is correctly intercepting all of my static assets, as well as my analytics (ensighten, etc). We're also loading in a document from an iframe on the page, but the request to get that document isn't being picked up by workbox.

Any idea why we can't intercept the iframe src request even though it's a regular `GET` request?

The way we've currently tested what routes are and are not being picked up is by adding a wildcard route at the very start of our service worker registration, i.e. `workbox.routing.registerRoute(/.*/, handleRoute)`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be due to a [bug in Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=439697).